# error during building val_description package

Tags: ros, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build the val_description package in my catkin workspace as shown in [this](https://gitlab.com/nasa-jsc-robotics/val_description) page. But i'm getting below errors:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267240/error-during-building-val_description-package/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2017-07-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-07-24**:
could you please provide a little more information? The link you provided gives us (me at least) a directory on their GitLab instance, but not any kind of instruction.

A little bit more of the CMake output would be useful as well.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2017-07-24**:
the link was little bit forwarded page, i've updated it now. what i did is simply downloaded the package in my catkin workspace and than try to build it using command catkin_make but i got above error.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2017-07-24**:
Which rosdistro are you using?

---

nvm -- I see you're using indigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error here is that the build is trying to run `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` and it's failing. The error output isn't included, but I suspect it's because it isn't running in a git repository.

It looks like you need to clone the repository with git instead of downloading a tarball.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1